# Existence of a homotopy cofibration with particular cofibre

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a finite, pointed, CW-complex. For $n \geq 1$, define the $n$-th *fat wedge*:

$$FW^n(X) := \bigcup_{i=1}^n X \times X \times... \times * \times ... \times X \subseteq \prod_{i=1}^nX$$

where the basepoint $*$ appears in the $i$-th factor in each of the $n$ pieces of the union.

The (genuine) cofibre of the inclusion into the product is the $n$-th smash product:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
FW^n(X) @>{i}>> \prod_{i=1}^n X @>{q}>> \bigwedge_{i=1}^n X
\end{CD}

Suppose that I have a space $C$ and a map $\mu$ such that $FW^n(X) \hookrightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n X$ is a representative of the homotopy cofibre of $\mu$. That is, I have the below homotopy cofibration sequence:

\begin{CD}
        C @>{\mu}>> FW^n(X) @>{\text{i}}>> \prod_{i=1}^n X @>{q}>> \bigwedge_{i=1}^nX \\
    \end{CD}

I wish to know when such a $C$ and $\mu$ exist, or what conditions are sufficient for existence.

I know that if $C$ (and $\mu$) exist, then $\Sigma C \simeq \bigwedge_{i=1}^n X$, and also $\prod_{i=1}^n X$ is the mapping cone on $\mu:C \rightarrow FW^n(X)$.

It is also true that the map $\mu:C \rightarrow FW^n(X)$ factors (up to homotopy) through the homotopy fibre of the inclusion $FW^n(X) \rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n X$ by the universal property of the homotopy fibre.

The above are all easy consequences of what is written down above, and are necessary conditions for the existence of $C$.

What is known about what conditions are sufficient (outside of trivial ones) for $C$ and $\mu$ to exist here in general?

Comment: If such $\mu$ exists at all, it needs to be a desuspension of $\bigwedge^nX\to \Sigma FW^n(X)$, so any condition that prevents $\bigwedge_i X$ from being a suspension will also prevent $\mu$ from existing. For example if $X$ has a non-trivial wedge product in cohomology, so does $\bigwedge_i X$ and so $\mu$ cannot exist.

Comment: I doubt this happens very often, but one place it does happen is $S^1 \vee S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \wedge S^1$.

Comment: In general there is not much that can be said. If each $X_i$ in the product (they may be distinct) is itself a mapping cone then in some cases you can iteratively construct a map $\mu$. The methods are detailed in appendix B.9 of Cornea, Lupton, Oprea and Tanre's book On Lusternik-Schnirelmann category, for instance.

Comment: To ask for $X^{\wedge n}$ to admit a desuspension is an obstruction for such a cofibre sequence as you desire to exist! On the other hand, for a $CW$-complex $Y$ if $b$ is the dimension of the bottom cell and $t$ is the dimension of the top cell then if $t\leqslant 2b-1$ the space $Y$ admits a desuspension, by an application of Freudenthal's suspension theorem. In specific examples, not fitting into above dimension sequence one has to know the Hopf invariant of the attaching maps(if you are in the metastable range) to decide about desuspsnsion. On a related topic, this space is related to...

Comment: the polyhedral product of Strickland which has been studies extensively in recent years, and I believe examples of these latter products and their desuspension exists in the literature.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. 

@DenisNardin, by wedge product in cohomology do you mean the usual cup product? 

user51223, can you explain your first sentence a little more? I do not understand in what way this is an obstruction. Also, in regards to your "related topic" - you may be interested to know that this is the exact context in which I am dealing with these things! :)

Comment: @Matt Yes, sorry. That was I typo. I meant the cup product (it's a fun elementary exercise to show that suspensions have trivial cup product structure on the reduced cohomology).